# Are the benefits of SFIO over STDIO still valid?

Tags: c, linux, io

I have just noticed about a library [SFIO](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.51.6574) for a safe and fast IO processing in C. But it is not very up to date. The last version of library is released in <strike>2005</strike> [2012](https://github.com/att/ast/tree/master/src/lib/libast) and I couldn't assess that if the claimed benefits of SFIO over STDIO are still valid with comparison to the recent releases of standard IO library. Also Would it be reasonable to use this library in a production code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer using standard stuffs instead of relying on a lib that is not maintained or developed anymore. Do tests however to know if your code really benefits from its usage. If it is not hard, develop your code with switches definible at compile time to use `sfio` or the standard approach, so that you can switch to one or another according to needs and if you notice `sfio` is giving problems.

Comment: Yeah probably you're right i should test this library in order to grasp the difference in my case. (But nowadays i'm really fed up with testing libraries, most of the libraries in C aren't documented well)

Comment: nonetheless testing is often required; a library being documented well or not. sfio description seems to improve stdio (some limits are still present afaik, but they are also implementaton specific, so it is hard to say what would be really better), but stdio is, well, standard, so I would rely on it in production code, until I have the time to make deeper tests and see how it benefits my code

Answer (score 1):

I am only aware of this fact this SFIO library claims to be more efficient, safe, and robust, yet I never bothered to try this library, as standard io library is always fine with me.
I want to ask what benefits they claim which you are not able to assess. can you give details and also the exact references.

Also I would really want to ask you why do you want to rely on some non standard library over standard one, what is your special purpose.

Anyways if there is no such special requirement I would suggest you to use only standard library.

Also as you have asked about using it in a production code, so my suggestion is a absolutely NO.

Thanks
Alok.Kr.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kumar, the reason that I wanted to use SFIO that because the standard library was too slow for the task i was working on and i wanted to know if somebody used this library(a lot of batch io process and need to be very fast). Actually i searched this library and found out that many open source libraries use this library. Like amarok, perl and graphviz. So thought that it is not that bad.